# difference between asp net core and asp net framework

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between ASP.NET Core Web (.NET Core) vs ASP.NET Core Web (.NET Framework)?

I don't see clearly the main difference between the two project types, actually which sense have the last one? .NET Core and .NET Framework?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908049/what-is-net-core

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core

Comment: If you need to run your ASP.Net project on something bother then a Windows host you would target your project to support .NET Core obviously